# Selected Item changed event handler TreeList

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

How can I add an event handler for when a Devexpress `TreeList` selection changes? Here's what I have that isn't working:

```
window.nList.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(nList_SelectedItemChanged);

private void nList_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(nList.CurrentCellValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the multi-select mode? The [SelectedItemChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_SelectedItemChangedtopic) and [SelectionChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTreeListControl_SelectionChangedtopic) events aren't fired if the [SelectionMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_SelectionModetopic) property is set to `MultiSelectMode.None`(default value).
Please use the [CurrentItemChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CurrentItemChangedtopic) event instead when single-selection mode is active.
This event occurs after the focused row has been changed (e.g. row focus moves to another data row).

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`TreeListControl.SelectionChanged`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTreeListControl_SelectionChangedtopic) event.
In `XAML`:

```html
<dxg:TreeListControl x:Name="treeListControl1" SelectedItemChanged="treeListControl1_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

Or in `c#`:

```cs
treeListControl1.SelectedItemChanged += treeListControl1_SelectedItemChanged;
```

Event handler method:

```
void treeListControl1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((YourClass)e.NewItem).SomeValue.ToString());
}
```